# How to show tax rate in magento order email?

Tags: magento-1.6

I need to show my current tax rate into the order email

Currently it is showing only word Tax and amount that is perfect in nature But

I want it to show **Tax(19.6%)** --------- 19.6 is the tax rate of my system for all products

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Encl: Order email link
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust this if you edit the file in your theme:
/app/design/frontend/your-pkg/default/template/tax/order/tax.phtml